# Need help on trying to extract comments from facebook posts using python

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, comments, facebook-access-token

I was trying the following code from Github : https://github.com/weijiekoh/scrape-fb-posts-and-comments I created access token and APP id, placed them in credentials.txt as instructed, however while running the
command:

```
scrape-fb-posts-and-comments vivekrmk$ python3 run.py --page https://www.facebook.com/allinwithchris --cred credentials.txt --posts-output output.csv --scrape-comments --comments-output comments.csv
```

I obtained the following error :

```
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
Error for URL https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/https://www.facebook.com/allinwithchris/posts/?fields=message,link,created_time,type,name,id,comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares,reactions.limit(0).summary(true)&limit=100&access_token=309131450111655|EAAEZAJ0ZAF1qcBANdqMjhHbsXDZChZCfw0uLLnZCm0ZBOrEhlW8cVoZBqfzSeok2I7pq89aNkiVcKwLwK1ZBUNI5trzc5knOAbRnesrvRBW7Y1ZBNFJCAOuN9JtBrjreTkPCT7LM5VoN4ZBR343nLbeU9ydQpC6uWdDa5QgKlQU6DYNeXFAAK0ZBqf4d9ZCgxZAeFb2sZD: 2020-06-20 18:45:38.602656
```

I also tried the facebook page id instead of URL and the facebook page name instead of URL, still I was getting error HTTP 400: Bad request.

Is there any other way to get the comments other than the app? How about trying Pythons Beautiful soup? The app requires permissions and would take many business days to get approval. Looking for suggestions, help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the requested URL is correct? In the log, it looks like two URLs concatenated together.

Comment: The page should be an ID not a URL.

Comment: @MilanCermak yes the URL is correct, your comment made me to think of attempting the script with the page name instead if URL, still i got the same error.

Comment: Thanks @Wizkid I have tried the facebook page id and the page name on separate attempts and still am facing the same error message. Also this code is from the year 2017, recently facebook have updated their policy- so that could be a reason… I guess I have hit a barrier here, thinking about beautiful soup, looking for reccomendations...

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to scrape them so API is the only option.